# Python OpenCV: Change background color to white

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone share the code for changing the background color of attached image to white, so that I can recognize the foreground the digits with OCR software?

[image]

Comment: The OpenCV docs/tutorials are very comprehensive, have a look there. If you have any specific problems with your code, ask here. However, this isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to gray, apply contrast and use threshold to get this result:
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("digits.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[...,0]
# edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 10,30)    
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5.0, tileGridSize=(32,32))
contrast = clahe.apply(blurred)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(contrast, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


while True:
  cv2.imshow("result", thresh)
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
      break
```

Comment: Really thanks!  However, Tesseract (OCR software) cannot recognize the digits correctly.

Comment: Well, this answers the question asked.  Please mark as solved. You may ask a specific OCR question about why it doesn't recognise the digits in another question. Have you tried to crop the image to the part with numbers?

Comment: @FredGuth Asking the Question author to mark your Answer as the accepted Answer is frowned upon. Voting along with using the accept is voluntary, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (Side note: No one seemed to have upvoted the Question.)